# Can pre-receive hook edit commits?

Tags: git, bash, githooks, git-bash

I'm building a pre-receive hook to check the name and email address of the author.

I'm able to easily check if the name/email address of the commit using,

```
while read oldsha newsha refname; do
        authorEmail=$(git log -1 --pretty=format:%ae $newsha)
        if [[ $(grep -w $authorEmail ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | wc -w) -gt 1 ]]; then
                        echo "Author Email: $authorEmail"
                        exit 0
                else
                        echo "Unauthorized Email"
                        exit 1
                fi
done
```

But instead of simply rejecting it, I want to replace the email with the right one.
I have authorized_keys set up like this,

```
environment="UserEmail=user@hostA" ssh-rsa AAAAAA... user@hostA
```

So I'd like to do something along the lines of

```
if [[ ... ]]; 
    then
        echo "Author Email: $authorEmail"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Unauthorized Email detected"
        echo "Replacing email with: $UserEmail"
        git commit --amend --author "something <$UserEmail>"
        exit 0
    fi
```

But as expected, the git commit --amend .. throws an error that this should be used in a working tree.
Is there any way I can accomplish this here in the pre-receive or possibly the update hook?

Answer (score 4):

Ankit,

I understand your motivation for wanting to edit a commit to correct what seems to be a "recoverable" error.  Modifying the commit authorsip is not the way to go about it.  Since changing a commit author changes the SHA-1 for the commit, the commit history between the local branch and the remote will be different as soon as the commit is pushed.  That is most definitely not what you want.

A better solution (if it is practical in your situation, of course) would be to add local prepare-commit-msg and/or commit-msg hooks to developers git repos.  You could then change the commit message before the commit is processed.  That would solve the history rewriting problem.  Unfortunately, you cannot FORCE a remote developer to use the hooks (`git commit --no-verify` will bypass the commit checks).

Therefore, I would recommend a combination approach.  Make it easy to get the email address right by providing local hooks to check and correct author problems before a commit is pushed.  Then, add the server hooks to prevent commits with invalid or unauthorized authors from being pushed.  Developers that follow the rules for your repo will not be inconvenienced (beyond adding the hooks), and your remote repo will not get populated with unauthorized commit authors.

On an related note, why go to the trouble of checking for unauthorized authors if all you are going to do is update the author to some default "valid" author?

Comment: This wasn't about rewriting the commit message. This was about rewriting the commit authorship metadata.

Comment: Whether you change the commit message or the commit metadata, the original problem is still present.  You end up with a new SHA-1 for the commit.  I modified my answer to reflect author changes rather than commit message changes.

Comment: @MichaelMilom So correct me if I'm wrong, if I change the commit author, it leads to a different SHA-1 and therefor a different history compared to local.  What would this imply? Would the developers have to pull from the remote again to be synced everytime?

Comment: I have considered using a combination, possibly with pre-commit or prepare-commit but like you said, its on the local and can be easily skipped using no-verify. That's why I was trying to accomplish this on the server end if at all possible.

Comment: The idea behind stopping the commit at the server is to force the developer to fix the problem if they choose to ignore the local hooks.  Other than that, there is no way that I know of to accomplish what you want to accomplish.  If this is satisfactory, please accept the answer (if you don't mind).  Thank you!